# How can I group distinct columns in a linq query?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

The following data is created by joining two sql tables together:

[image: My data]

I would like to group together distinct rows of DateStamp/UserName/StudentName/InstructorName/TableName/PrimaryKey (I'll call this 'group records') and then group under these ColumnName/PreviousValue/NewValue (I'll call this 'subgroup records')

The end result would be that I could iterate through the 'group records' - there would be 5. In each 'group record', I could then iterate through the 'subgroup records'. The 5 groups would contain 3, 2, 5, 2 and 1 subgroup records respectively.

What would be the syntax to create a query to do this? Ideally this would be in a vb.net linq syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group using an anonymous key composed of those properties.  Here's the syntax for the C# query:

```
var query = from row in joinedTable
            group new // subgroup record
                {
                    row.ColumnName,
                    row.PreviousValue,
                    row.NewValue
                }
            by new    // group record
                {
                    row.DateStamp,
                    row.UserName,
                    row.StudentName,
                    row.InstructorName,
                    row.TableName,
                    row.PrimaryKey
                };
```

The corresponding VB query:

```
Dim query = From row In joinedTable    _
            Group                      _
                row.ColumnName,        _
                row.PreviousValue,     _
                row.NewValue           _
            By                         _
                row.DateStamp,         _
                row.UserName,          _
                row.StudentName,       _
                row.InstructorName,    _
                row.TableName,         _
                row.PrimaryKey         _
            Into SubGroup = Group
```

Comment: I now just get the utterly cryptic error of "Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree." on the second query

Comment: @Neil: Hmm, not sure about what to do with that.  See if getting the `joinedTable.AsEnumerable` helps.

Comment: It's beyond the scope of this question. It is because I am performing this grouping query on another query and I think I needed to force the first to enumerate. I honestly can't stand the sight of linq when I get issues like this! Thanks!